# Where should I be placing subscribe(on:)/receive(on:) in my Combine chain? Also, storing .share() Publishers

Tags: swift, thread-safety, scheduler, combine

I am trying organize and design a Combine-based API framework for communicating and reacting to [OBS Studio](http://obsproject.com) (live-streaming software), using [obs-websocket](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/). I've written my own Combine Subject-wrapped Publisher for WebSocket communication, and am now using *that* to talk with OBS. I've created Publishers for sending request messages to OBS, as well as listening for event messages emitted by OBS. I've also been developing this alongside an actual SwiftUI app that uses the new framework.

While developing the app, I found that there are some complex combinations of requests and event listeners that I would need to use around the app. So, as part of the framework, I built out a few Publishers that merge results from an initial request and event listeners for changes to those properties. Testing these out, they worked great, so I committed to git and attempted to implement them in my app code. Instead, they didn't work consistently. I realized that by using the same Publishers in multiple places of the app, it was creating duplicate Publishers (because almost all Publishers are structs/value-types).

So, I found an article about implementing the `.share()` operator (https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/using-combines-share-operator-to-avoid-duplicate-work/) and I tried it out. Specifically, I set up a system for storing the different publishers that could be recalled while still active. Some of them are keyed by relevant values (like keying by the URL in the article), but others are just single values, as there wouldn't be more than one of that publisher at a time. That worked fine.

```
class PublisherStore {
    typealias ResponsePublisher = AnyPublisher<OBSRequestResponse, Error>
    var responsePublishers = [String: ResponsePublisher]()
    
    typealias BatchResponsePublisher = AnyPublisher<OpDataTypes.RequestBatchResponse, Error>
    var batchResponsePublishers = [String: BatchResponsePublisher]()
    
    typealias EventPublisher = AnyPublisher<OBSEvent, Error>
    var eventPublishers = [OBSEvents.AllTypes: EventPublisher]()
    var eventGroupPublishers = [String: EventPublisher]()
    
    var anyOpCode: AnyPublisher<UntypedMessage, Error>? = nil
    var anyOpCodeData: AnyPublisher<OBSOpData, Error>? = nil
    var allMessagesOfType = [OBSEnums.OpCode: AnyPublisher<OBSOpData, Error>]()
    
    var studioModeState: AnyPublisher<Bool, Error>? = nil
    var currentSceneNamePair: AnyPublisher<SceneNamePair, Error>? = nil
    var sceneList: AnyPublisher<[OBSRequests.Subtypes.Scene], Error>? = nil
    var sceneItemList = [String: AnyPublisher<[OBSRequests.Subtypes.SceneItem], Error>]()
    var activeSceneItemList: AnyPublisher<[OBSRequests.Subtypes.SceneItem], Error>? = nil
    var sceneItemState = [String: AnyPublisher<SceneItemStatePair, Error>]()
}
```

Where I started running into issues is attempting to implement the final part of the article: adding a custom `DispatchQueue`. What's been confusing me is the placement of `subscribe(on:)`/`receive(on:)` operators, and which ones should be to `DispatchQueue.main` vs. my internal custom queue. Here's what I have in my primary chain that calls one of the custom merged Publishers:

```
try connectToOBS()
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in print("Main thread outside before?:", Thread.isMainThread) })
    // <1>
    .tryFlatMap { _ in try studioModeStatePublisher() } // <- custom Publisher
    // <2>
    .handleEvents(receiveOutput: { _ in print("Main thread outside after?:", Thread.isMainThread) })
    .output(in: 0..<4)
    .sink(receiveCompletion: { print("Sink completion:", $0); expectation1.fulfill() },
          receiveValue: { _ in })
    .store(in: &observers)
```

I have `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)`

Should I be placing `.receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)` at <1> or <2>? When I put it at <2> or leave it out, I don't get any print outs past the custom publisher. **If I put it at <1>, it works, but is that the right way to do it?** Here is the code for the custom publisher (sorry for it being a bit messy):

```
public func getStudioModeStateOnce() throws -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
    return try sendRequest(OBSRequests.GetStudioModeEnabled())
        .map(\.studioModeEnabled)
        // If error is thrown because studio mode is not active, replace that error with false
        .catch { error -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> in
            guard case Errors.requestResponseNotSuccess(let status) = error,
                  status.code == .studioModeNotActive else { return Fail(error: error).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
            return Just(false)
                .setFailureType(to: Failure.self)
                .eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

public func studioModeStatePublisher() throws -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
    // <3>
    if let pub = publishers.studioModeState {
        return pub
    }
    
    // Get initial value
    let pub = try getStudioModeStateOnce()
        // Merge with listener for future values
        .merge(with: try listenForEvent(OBSEvents.StudioModeStateChanged.self, firstOnly: false)
                .map(\.studioModeEnabled))
        .removeDuplicates()
        .receive(on: sessionQueue) // <- this being what Sundell's article suggested.
        .handleEvents(receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in
            self?.publishers.studioModeState = nil
        })
        .share()
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    
    // <4>
    publishers.studioModeState = pub
    return pub
}
```

Calls at <3> and <4> probably need to be done on the `sessionQueue`. **What would be the best practice for that?** The deepest level of publisher that this relies on looks like this:

```
try self.wsPublisher.send(msg, encodingMode: self.encodingProtocol)
    // <5>
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

**Should I put** `.receive(on: sessionQueue)` **at <5>?** Even when the tests work, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. Sorry for such a long thing, but I tried to add as much detail as possible and tried to bold my questions. Any and all help would be welcomed, and I'd be happy to provide any extra details if needed. Thanks!

**Edit:** I've realized that it was actually subscribing to the stored Publisher and would receive values if the value changed in OBS post-subscription. But the issue of receiving the most recent value is the issue. I replaced `.share()` with the `.shareReplay` idea from this article: (https://www.onswiftwings.com/posts/share-replay-operator/). Again, it works in my testing (including delays in subscription), but still doesn't receive the most recent value when used in my SwiftUI app. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If you want to have <3> and <4> run on the sessionQueue, then put receive(on:) at <1>. That's how that method will run on the sessionQueue. This would also be consistent with the Sundell article. As for your question about <5>, I can't tell what that code is doing. This article is pretty good, you might find it helpful: https://trycombine.com/posts/subscribe-on-receive-on/

Comment: Thanks for the article, I'll take a look. The main thing is that <1> and <2> will be code that can be called anywhere by anyone using the library, as opposed to internally. That means that sessionQueue won't be accessible from <1> and <2>. As you can see, I already put receive(on:) between <3> and <4> so the stored instance of it is cleared on the right thread. The thing I'm unsure about is which parts of the pipeline should be on which thread. I'm printing out if it's on the main thread at different points, just not sure what it was supposed to be. I'll report back.

Comment: @RobC ok after reading the article, I tried the following combination:

(1) Kept any subscribe(on:)/receive(on:) out of <5>.
(2) Added both subscribe(on: DispatchQueue.global()) and receive(on: DispatchQueue.global()) at <1>.
(3) Added receive(on: DispatchQueue.main) at <2>.
(4) Kept the receive(on: sessionQueue) between <3> and <4>.

I settled on leaving sessionQueue for exclusively accessing the stored publishers. It worked, but as soon as I tested with a second subscriber to the publisher, neither subscriber received any values. Thoughts?